# Namerror while using tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, menubar

Hey guys my code for creating a menubar widget is:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Asd(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.menubar = tk.Menu(self)
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.filemenu = tk.Menu(self.menubar,tearoff=0)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu = self.filemenu)
        self.filemenu.add_command(label = "Input-file")
        self.filemenu.add_command(label = "Output-file")

root=tk.Tk()
app=Asd(master=root)
app.master.title("Testprogramm")
app.config(menu=self.menubar)
app.mainloop()
```

The error is "name 'self' is not defined" and referrs to the line 
"app.config(menu=self.menubar)"

Does anyone know how to fix it, since self.menubar is in the **init** method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use `self` outside of the scope of a class. You also have the problem that you're trying to attach the menubar to a frame. Only toplevel windows (instances of `Tk` and `Toplevel`) can have a menubar associated with it.

You need to change the offending line to this:

```
root.config(menu=app.menubar)
```

Comment: ah ok i canged the line to your answer and it works, thank you ! 
can you elaborate on why i need to make said change, or rather how come i define it as self.menubar and use that in the method but in the root.config command i don´t use menu=app.self.menubar?

Comment: @James: this is a fundamental part of python objects. Inside an object, the object refers to itself with `self`. Outside of the object, you refer to the object by whatever name you used to assign the object to.

Comment: ah ok and because i´m outside of the object while using the root.config command i need to refer to it with the assigned name